Google Apps Script error: "GoogleJsonResponseException: API call to drive.files.insert failed with error: Bad Request"
I'm trying to trigger a Google Apps Script to copy an attached xlsx file from a Gmail email to a Google Sheet, but I'm getting the following error:
GoogleJsonResponseException: API call to drive.files.insert failed with error: Bad Request
fetch   @ fetch.gs:17

Line 17 in my code is:
var convertedSpreadsheetId = Drive.Files.insert({ mimeType: MimeType.GOOGLE_SHEETS }, xlsxBlob).id;
And this is the full code before line 17:
function fetch() {
  var searchQuery = "in:inbox from:email@domain.com has:attachment filename:Stockfile filename:.xlsx";
  var threads = GmailApp.search(searchQuery);

  if (threads.length > 0) {
    var latestThread = threads[0];
    var latestEmail = latestThread.getMessages()[0];
    var attachments = latestEmail.getAttachments();

    if (attachments.length > 0) {
      for (var i = 0; i < attachments.length; i++) {
        var attachment = attachments[i];
        var attachmentName = attachment.getName();

        if (attachmentName.indexOf("stockfile") === 0) {
          var xlsxBlob = attachment;
          var convertedSpreadsheetId = Drive.Files.insert({ mimeType: MimeType.GOOGLE_SHEETS }, xlsxBlob).id;
          var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(convertedSpreadsheetId).getSheets()[0];
          var data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();

I'm not exactly sure what the issue is, but I should point out that this code was working for months in 2022. I've only just gotten back to it and for some reasons I can't get it to work. I'm not sure what changed, in the code and/or in Google Apps Scripts.
The Drive services is set to v2, I've tried changing it to v3 but then Drive.Files.insert is not a function in v3.
